# delete ubuntu completely from hard drive

Tags: uninstall

i want to completely delete Ubuntu from my hard drive and then want to install window on it. Please help me as soon as possible.

after installing window i will install Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to delete Ubuntu, just install Windows using the normal installation procedure.  It will overwrite Ubuntu.

The installer may ask if you want to overwrite the entire drive - including all partitions - to install Windows.  If it asks this, this is what you want.

Further help with Windows installation is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot from a USB stick or a CD and then reformat your hard drive.
I suggest booting a live Linux, then run

```
fdisk /dev/sdx
```

where sdx is your hard drive.
You can use o to create a new dos partition table and then w to write it to the disk. Windows should be able to do the rest on installation.
If you want to delete it safely, you can use

```
 dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdx
```

which will fill your drive with random data. This may take depending on the drive several hours.
EDIT:typo